# how to send stdin into perl program by batch file?

Tags: perl, command-line

I would like to process  many file/ string into perl and do not wait stdin responded  from batch file,.How would be the batch file?

for instance I have test.pl and the content is

```
my $o=<STDIN>;

print "$o\n";

my $c=<STDIN>;

print "$c\n";
```

And a batch file executes the test.pl with different stdin at any time

Consider that the functionality of the batch file would be

```
perl test.pl <stdin> <stdin> 
perl test.pl <stdin> <stdin> 
perl test.pl <stdin> <stdin> 
perl test.pl <stdin> <stdin>
```

Then I wonder how to send the stdin into the test.pl.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to use @ARGV to receive data. It should be as follows :

```
my $o=$ARGV[0];

print "$o\n";

my $c=$ARGV[1];

print "$c\n";
```

You can **execute the program** as follows :

```
perl test.pl argument_1a argument_2a
```

You will get **output** as

```
argument_1a
argument_2a
```